# Evaluating $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{5n}\cdot \left(-1\right)^n\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, power-series

I am trying to find the behaviour of a power series in one of the two sides of the convergene of

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{5n}}{4^n}\left(x-7\right)^n$

and I want to check the first term when x = 3. so first I check if the limit goes to 0 and I'm having some problem.

Comment: In terms of the title, $\sqrt{5n}\cdot \left(-1\right)^n$ diverges as $n$ increases

Comment: How is it proven?

Comment: For any $k$, you have $|\sqrt{5n}\cdot \left(-1\right)^n| > k$  for all $n > k^2$ so there cannot be a limit